# Coding Debugging

Tags: arduino-uno

This program is supposed to act as a Decimal To Binary Converter, the LeD's acting as output.
The problem is that this function returns Garbage Value

```
const int LED1 =1, LED2 =3, LED3 =5;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode (LED1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (LED2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (LED3, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  int x = 0;
  x = Serial.read();
  x = x-48;
  switch(x){
    case 0:
      digitalWrite (LED1, LOW);
      digitalWrite (LED2, LOW);
      digitalWrite (LED3, LOW);
      break;
    case 1:
      digitalWrite (LED1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (LED2, LOW);    
      digitalWrite (LED3, LOW);
      break;
      case 2:
      digitalWrite (LED1, LOW);
      digitalWrite (LED2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (LED3, LOW);
      break;
      case 3:
      digitalWrite (LED1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (LED2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (LED3, LOW);
      break;
      case 4:
      digitalWrite (LED1, LOW);
      digitalWrite (LED2, LOW);
      digitalWrite (LED3, HIGH);
      break;
      case 5:
      digitalWrite (LED1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (LED2, LOW);
      digitalWrite (LED3, HIGH);
      break;
      case 6:
      digitalWrite (LED1, LOW);
      digitalWrite (LED2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (LED3, HIGH);
      break;
      case 7:
      digitalWrite (LED1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (LED2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite (LED3, HIGH);
      break;
  }
 Serial.write(x); 
}
```

Comment: If you want some help, you should at least put some effort in writing a decent question: What are you trying to achieve? What have you done so far? What do you expect your program to do? What is it doing instead?

Answer (score 7):

That massive program can be compressed into just a handful of lines:

```
const int LED1 = 1, 
          LED2 = 3, 
          LED3 = 5;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode (LED1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode (LED2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode (LED3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        int x = Serial.read();
        x = x - '0';
        digitalWrite(LED1, x & 0x01);
        digitalWrite(LED2, x & 0x02);
        digitalWrite(LED3, x & 0x04);
        Serial.print(x);
    }
}
```

Note the use of Serial.print() not Serial.write().  If you use Serial.write() then it prints the ASCII character associated with the number you feed it - in your case characters 0 to 7 (none of which are printable).

Also, unless you check for there actually being something available for you to read from the serial you'll only get a brief flicker of something meaningful (too fast for the eye to see) and then it will just return -1, which with 48 subtracted from it would be -49, which would be "complete garbage".

Comment: How does x & 0x01 works?

Comment: It's called a *bitwise* operation. I returns just the first bit of *x*, so 0 or 1.  With 0x02 it returns the second bit, so 0 or 2. 0x04 returns the third bit, so 0 or 4.  0 is LOW, anything above 0 is HIGH.

Comment: why do we use 0X04 and not use 0X03 if we want the third bit?

Comment: Because 0x03 is the first two bits combined. 1+2=3. Binary.

Comment: So we are moving according to according to numbers that are 2^(something) ??

Comment: That is what binary is, Yes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues:

- The function `loop()` doesn't return anything, by definition. Functions that do return a value return it with a statement like `return(someValue); Did you mean to say that it *prints* garbage on the terminal?
- If you want to print a value on the terminal, you need to use the the `Serial.print(someValue)` function; `Serial.write()` sends a binary value and that is probably not what you wanted. The binary values 0 - 9 represent non-printing characters so I'm not surprised that the terminal printed some odd graphic characters.

    -